# Can't deploy Firebase Cloud Function due to error with JSON.stringify() error

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a cloud function for my react native app that sends a notification to users when a new node appears in the database. To do so, I'm using Expo's Push API as shown here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/guides/push-notifications and following a tutorial available here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2D6J10fhA4

I've been able to acquire device tokens and save them to my database just fine. However, I'm unable to deploy the function to my database because of an error that says:

31:27 Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ,

It's throwing a fatal error at the line 'body: JSON.stringify(messages)' as if it expects a comma right after 'stringify'. I'm very unsure of how to proceed from here and can't seem to find any posts tackling this specific issue.

Any help and/or advice is appreciated! Thank you.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

let fetch = require('node-fetch');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database.ref('Omicron-Pi')
.onCreate(event => {
  const root = event.data.ref.root;
  let messages = [];

  root.child('Omicron-Pi/profiles').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      let pushToken = childSnapshot.val().pushToken;
        if (pushToken) {
          messages.push({
            to: pushToken,
            body: 'New Node added'
          });
        }
    });
    return Promise.all(messages);
  }).then(messages => {
    fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', [
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(messages)
    ]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `fetch()` is an object with initialization properties, but you are passing an array.

To fix it, use `{}` instead of `[]`:

```
fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(messages)
});
```

To learn more, read the [documentation on how to use fetch on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch).

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to fix that error, but now two others have appeared...
 
"3:13  error  'node-fetch' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S node-fetch' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies" and

"14:3   error  Expected catch() or return                                                                        promise/catch-or-return"

I have tried to run 'npm install -S node-fetch' for the first error but unfortunately, it persists. I'm unsure about how to tackle the second error.

Comment: That seems like a completely different problem. Did you search for other questions with that error message yet. They're bound to point towards adding the `node-fetch` module to your `package.json` file.